# Mixing authentication types in Apache

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication, mercurial

Currently, I'm using Apache to host my project repos (mercurial) and use Kerberos auth for users to push. The same Kerberos password is used to log in through SSH and there is a LDAP backend for user info (group, $HOME, default shell).

Now, I'm a bit paranoid and I want to periodically back up and push any changes I may have made where I may have forgotten to commit them.

I can do the commit just fine:

```
hg commit -u backup -m "Periodic commit"
```

However, I want to push and have it show up as the `backup` user.

I know one option is to create a new Kerberos user called `backup` and then I can push that way, but if my machine is ever compromised I don't want someone logging into my servers with the `backup` credentials.

I think that without a corresponding LDAP entry a the `backup` user should not be able to log in, but it leaves an unsettling feeling in my stomach.

---

That's all background information though. My question is, can I have both Kerberos and File based authentication in Apache? If so, how?

Here is the relevant part of my `vhost.conf`:

```
<Location /repos>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "repos"

  AuthType Kerberos
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd on
  Krb5Keytab /path/to/keytab
  KrbAuthRealms REALM.TLD
  KrbServiceName http/host.realm.tld@REALM.TLD
  KrbLocalUserMapping On

  AuthLDAPUrl ldap://ldap/ou=People,dc=realm,dc=tld?uid
  <LimitExcept Get>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would probably be to set up a second location block with the alternate authentication.